# AKAmplitudeTracker - return 0.0 Value

Tags: audiokit

I have following code

class Audio {

let mic: AKMicrophone!

let ampTracker: AKAmplitudeTracker!

init() {

```
  mic = AKMicrophone()
  ampTracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(mic)

  AudioKit.output = mic

  try? AudioKit.start()
```

}

let audio = Audio()

@IBAction func start(_ sender: UIButton) {
      if audio.mic.isStopped == true {

```
  audio.mic.start()
  audio.ampTracker.start() 
  for i in 0...50 {
  print(audio.ampTracker.amplitude)
  usleep(200000)
  } 
  } else {
  audio.mic.stop()
  }
```

So, Microphone is working ok - I hear the signal in headphones, but AKAmplitudeTracker always print value 0.0. 
I also tried to use AKMicrophoneTracker - the same result
it is on Iphone Simulator in xCode

Answer (score 0):

@distapcher,

In order to modify the mic and ampTracker parameters, their instance variables should be changed to vars, instead of lets:

```
var mic: AKMicrophone!
var ampTracker: AKAmplitudeTracker!
```

Comment: Hi Mark! I changed them to var. but it did not help ( the same 0.0 Value with working microphone..

Comment: @distapcher, would you be willing to post an example project to GitHub for me to test with? I'm unclear what you're using with the `i` variable in the for loop.

Comment: Unfortunately I don have GitHub now, but i is changed to _ in this loop. It is just loop for snapshot amplitude every 0.2 sec